Is changing the signature of a callback a breaking change?
In Javascript, should appending to the signature of a callback be considered a breaking change?
I.e. given an operation op(target, callback) should changing it from callback(item, index, array) to callback(item, index, array, root) result in a new major release according to semver?
The spec specifies:

increment the MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes

and the two signatures are not incompatible, as the new one encompasses the old, seeming to suggest a new major version is not required.
On the other hand, consider this (admittedly slightly contrived) example:
function doTheThing(item, index, array, doItDifferently) {
    if (doItDifferently) 
        // Do something unusual and amazing with the arguments
    else
        // Do the same old boring thing with the arguments
}
// Use doTheThing as a callback to the operation:
op(target, doTheThing)
// doTheThing is also used directly:
doTheThing(arr[0],0,arr,true)

doTheThing is a valid callback, but might be used elsewhere in the code in its more elaborate form. This would break if the callback signature were changed.
Update
Wow, lots of really good food for thought. I see no consensus, but there seems to be a majority in favor of considering it a breaking change, and, hence, a major release. The more I have been thinking about it, the more that seems right to me, as well, and I think that is what I will do. It's definitely the safer option.
I had posted this as more or less an abstract question, not expecting it to spark so much debate. To facilitate further discussion, the library in question is object-selectors, a selector language for complex and deeply nested Javascript objects, and specifically, the perform operation.

Are you asking about your library changing how op calls it's parameter, or what your library passes to op?

I'm asking about how op, which is exported by my library, calls its callback parameter.

If some clients may need to change their code due to the change, it's a breaking change.

"a majority in favor considering it a breaking change" - well, thanks for accepting my answer. Note, however, though I first thought it is a breaking change,  my final answer says, it depends on how it is implemented. It will not necessarily become one when one is careful.

@DocBrown Yes, I saw that, and I saw the change, too. You're essentially saying, make the new feature opt-in, and it's guaranteed to not be breaking change. I've mentally added it to my list of options, but still more leaning toward just accepting it is a breaking change. I might offer an opt-out, though, to ease migration.

It depends on how the call of the callback changes!
Let's say in V1.0.0 of a library or component where op resides, the function looks like this:
 function op(target, callback)
 {
     // ...
     callback(item, index, array);
 }

and the next version of that component, it is
 function op(target, callback)
 {
     // ... everything else remains ...
     callback(item, index, array, true);
 }

and you ask whether the next version's version number should be V1.1.0 or V2.0.0, right?
In a strongly typed and compiled language, it would be clear that clients need to be changed and recompiled after such a change, thus it would clearly be a breaking change. In JavaScript, however, this will not force any recompilation, and client code which passed in just 3-parameter callbacks would not behave differently in conjunction with this change, since the value of the fourth parameter will simply be ignored. This gives the impression this kind of change might be backwards compatible.
Unfortunately, as long as you did not clearly state in the V1.0.0 API description that valid callback must ignore anything beyond the 3rd parameter, you don't know if some of your clients had passed a 4-parameter version of callback formerly into the "V1.0.0", since JavaScript does not forbid this. For a callback which accepts 3 or 4 parameters, the change in the component looks effectively like a change from
 callback(item, index, array, undefined);

to
 callback(item, index, array, true);

and that is clearly a different behaviour of the component.
Hence, in the next API version, there is some risk the change might cause different behaviour for a client at run time - a "breaking change". That means, SEMVER will require to use "V2.0.0", and not "V1.1.0".
Now imagine op being part of some component C, and the "next version" of C gets a new boolean flag variable newFeatureActivated which defaults to false. Then it will be possible to implement the behaviour in a truly backwards compatible way, like this:
 function op(target, callback)
 {
     // ... 
     if(!newFeatureActivated)
         callback(item, index, array);
     else
         callback(item, index, array, true);
 }

Now, any unchanged client which uses C the old way will have the new feature deactivated by default. Hence passing in 4-parameter callback will behave exactly like before. So when one is careful, there is no breaking change, and the version number V1.1.0 will be appropriate.
In short, the fact alone the callback's signature is changed in a backwards compatible manner is not enough to guarantee backwards compatibility - one has to also be very careful to keep the calls to any callback backwards compatible as well.

Hard disagree. Breaking stuff for users relying on undocumented behavior is not a backwards incompatible change. If a user expects an unspecified fourth parameter to always be undefined (because JS), that’s on them. Otherwise, one could claim every change is a breaking change. For example, if I (undocumentedly) use /tmp, but switch to in-memory cache, that’s not a breaking change, even if some user decided they’d access the files while I am. Alternatively, is adding a new property to a JS object I return a breaking change because some user named their own prop the same way on that object?

@ColeTobin: even if you don't like it, such things can break client's code, and when you write libraries for a huge number of clients, you will be better off to either increase the major version number, or to be careful to make a more backwards compatible implementation.  Those two options are rarely both that terrible that it pays off to refuse them both, Unfortunately, Hyrum's law is based on factual observations, not some pathological cases.

.. see also Flater's IMHO correct answer, who states that a any change which breaks a possible usage (even if that usage is based on side effects) counts as a breaking change.  Of course, there are edge cases where the literal interpreation of "observable behaviour" might go too far,

As long as clients don't need to update their code to achieve the same behavior as the old version, and this change is backwards-compatible, it is not a breaking change for JavaScript. Callers are not obligated to specify every parameter passed to a function. This assumes callback(item, index, array) in the new library version is semantically equivalent to the same call in the old version. If the behavior of callback(item, index, array) is different in the new version, then it would be considered a breaking change.
The addition of a callback parameter in JavaScript is kind of like supporting a new overload. You could justify increasing the minor version number, making this  a backwards-compatible feature release instead. However, if the addition of the new callback parameter corrects a defect, then increase the patch version. This would be applicable if you had distributed the previous version of the library and included documentation that clients could use callback(item, index, array, root), but your library mistakenly did not pass root.
The intention of the change matters as well.

"As long as clients don't need to update their code, and this change is backwards-compatible" - hm, didn't the OP show as an example where doTheThing needs to be updated, because the change is not that backwards compatible in JavaScript as it looks at a first glance?

@DocBrown: the second sentence addresses doTheThing - or at least I thought people would make that connection. Perhaps I need to clarity my answer?

What the second paragraph adresses is clear, still I think the statement that this would be a "backwards-compatible feature release" is probably not correct - there is a possible case where this code does not behave backwards-compatible.

I see what you mean. I was equating "clients don't need to update their code" with "no change in behavior." I should clarify that first sentence. I assumed a change in behavior would require clients to update their code to achieve the same behavior as before.

Javascript does not only allow parameters to be omitted, it also allows a function to be called with more parameters than it actually has declared. So when the change inside op is from a line callback(a,b,c) to callback(a,b,c,true), existing code may behave completely differently.

@DocBrown: I see what you mean. In my opinion, if the client chooses to pass too many parameters, which breaks a future update, I wouldn't consider that a breaking change from the perspective of the library. The client has a bug that needs to be fixed. We get lots of these gray areas with JavaScript, and I think at some point you just need to draw a line, otherwise the both of us could think of a thousand ways client code could break. It's a balancing act. You don't want every change to be "breaking." Client code has some responsibility here to use the library as it was intended.

Ok, I also see what you mean. Still the OPs example is not about a bug to be fixed, it is about a 3-parameter callback parameter which gets a 4-parameter function passed in intentionally (with an argument why this could be reasonable), and then a change to the call inside the operation (for what reason ever). If the API's documentation would have stated that the callback must ignore more than 3 parameters, then passing the 4-parameter version could have seen as a bug right from the start.

... after thinking again about it, I changed my own answer a bit, please have a look.

"Client code has some responsibility here to use the library as it was intended." I agree with that, on the other hand client code may have taken a pre-existing (and elsewhere-used) function of higher arity and used it as the 3-parameter-callback to op. This is fairly common is JS, I would consider this "responsible" usage. Like imagine if  Array#reduce's callback did not have the index and array parameter, doing array.reduce(Math.sum) would be perfectly fine, but adding index and array to the callback signature would break that. I think this is what @DocBrown is saying, right?

@BadIdeaException: that's how I interpreted your sentence "doTheThing is a valid callback, but might be used elsewhere in the code in its more elaborate form".  That's a sensible way of using a lib, neither a "bug" nor an abusage. Moreoever, I think Greg's answer has a real flaw which the upvoters must have overlooked: it says "callback(item, index, array) in the new library version" and derives it's conclusions from that. But  callback is not part of the library, it's not the subject of the versioning here.

My understanding was that the signature of the callback is part of the versioned library. Is that not correct, @BadIdeaException? If so, then that was not clear in the question.

Yes, the signature of the callback is documented and hence part of the versioned library. Otherwise, clients would never be able to use it.

I'm sidestepping the specific example because I feel it's inefficient to try and define breaking changes on a case by case basis. The definition of a breaking change, at its very core, is this:
If every possible usage (i.e. consuming code) of your previous version will keep working in the newer version, then it's not a breaking change. Otherwise, it's a breaking change.
Some notes on that:

Note that I said every possible usage, not just every actual usage. It's not productive to label changes as breaking/not breaking based on you knowing that your consumers are doing things one way and not another way. You shouldn't be aware of your consumers' specific implementation, you only need to focus on what you've made possible for your consumers to do with your code.
"Keep working" implies not just that it compiles, but also that the behavior is unchanged. This includes the returned data and any side effects. To the consumer, the upgrade from the previous to the new version needs to be invisible, nothing should change about any existing consumption of your code.

So, back to your question:

I.e. given an operation op(target, callback) should changing it from callback(item, index, array) to callback(item, index, array, root) result in a new major release according to semver?

If the language you're working in allows consumers to omit trailing parameters (in C# they're called "optional" parameters, I don't know other names), then the introduction of such an optional parameter does not break existing consumers' code.
If this requires the consumers to update their code, even if it's just passing in a null, that's a breaking change. Any update which forces a consumer to update the code is a breaking change, by its very definition.

Note that changes to optional parameters might be source-compatible (not requiring a change in client code) but binary-incompatible (requiring client code to be recompiled).  This is the case with .NET.

@Craig: Good callout. Depends on the tech stack and how the consumer loads the library.

@Craig In C++ if there is an optional parameter, say “int x = 0”, then calling without the parameter is compiled exactly like passing 0. But not sure if I would count a required recompile as a breaking change, probably not. Obviously you have to re-link, so why not re-compile? And your build system might do that automatically anyway.

It does not (generally) require clients to update their code, provided they are not using a higher-arity function as the callback. Which (because JS), they might, the question is: Is that on them, or is it my responsibility? In other words: The three documented parameters are clearly part of the contract, but is the lack of further parameters also part of the contract?

@BadIdeaException The question is not whether consumers might be using your library in a way that the upgrade might break for them. If it is possible, regardless of whether you have any or no active knowledge about a consumer doing so; then it is a breaking change for all intents and purposes and should be treated as such.

@gnasher729 Consider the alternative of a dynamically-loaded library where the content (but not the signature) of the function changed.  That would be a drop-in replacement without needing to recompile the client (both source-compatible and binary-compatible).  When the default parameter changes, now you need to recompile and/or relink, so it's source-compatible (you don't need to retype it) but not binary-compatible.

Question 1: Does my code compile and run after I switch to the changed library?
Question 2: Does my unmodified code run without any change in its behaviour?
If the answer is “Yes” twice then it is a non-breaking change. What kind of change doesnt matter. If I passed a callback, and you changed the signature, then I would expect that my code doesnt compile. In that case it is a breaking change.

Javascript is an interpreted language, and its way of handling function arguments is sufficiently lenient that changing the callback signature does not prevent legacy code from running unchanged.

In that case Question 1 is answered, and Question 2 needs answering: Does the unmodified code run without any change in its behaviour?
